# CSS hover effect applying to everything but h4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following scenario:

I'm using bootstrap to develop this site. When I hover into a list group, everything is suppose to have a trnasition into a blue background color and the text should go white. It works though the styles don't apply to the H4.

Here's the css code:

```
.styled-group-right-item{
    padding: 20px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
.limited-list-group{
    height: auto;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.author-pubdate-info{
    font-weight: bold;
}
.list-group-item-switchhon-blog:hover{
    transition: all 0.5s ease !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color: #2980b9 !important;
}
.list-group-item-switchhon-blog{
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

And here is the markup:

```
<div class="list-group limited-list-group">
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item clearfix list-group-item-switchhon-blog">
                       <div class="pull-left">
                           <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" class="btn-center">
                       </div> 
                        <div class="styled-group-right-item">
                            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</h4>
                            <p class="list-group-item-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eget interdum libero. Vivamus pharetra faucibus.</p>
                            <span class="author-pubdate-info">Autor: John Doe | Fecha: 11 de Noviembre de 2014</span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

And here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y7d5fm1w/

What I have tried so far: add another class like this:

```
.list-group-item-switchhon-blog:hover h4{
    transition: all 0.5s ease !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color: #2980b9 !important;
}
```

But that creates a very funny effect, try it on fiddle, it's not good.

Any ideas how to apply the styles into the h4, please I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the style to the `h4` *as well*. **Also, place the `transition` on the non hover state**; This ensures that the transition will apply in and out of the hover state.

**Aside:** If you change `overflow-y: scroll` to `overflow-y: auto`, you will only get a scrollbar if the content actually overflows.

### Changes

```
.list-group-item-switchhon-blog, .list-group-item-switchhon-blog h4 { /* transition here */
 transition: all 0.5s ease !important;
}
.list-group-item-switchhon-blog:hover {
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color: #2980b9 !important;
}
.list-group-item-switchhon-blog:hover h4 { /* add this */
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

### Working example

```css
.styled-group-right-item {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
.limited-list-group {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.author-pubdate-info {
  font-weight: bold !important;
}
.list-group-item-switchhon-blog, .list-group-item-switchhon-blog h4 {
  transition: all 0.5s ease !important;
}
.list-group-item-switchhon-blog:hover {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #2980b9 !important;
}
.list-group-item-switchhon-blog:hover h4 {
  color: #fff !important;
}
.list-group-item-switchhon-blog {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="list-group limited-list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item clearfix list-group-item-switchhon-blog">
    <div class="pull-left">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" class="btn-center">
    </div>
    <div class="styled-group-right-item">
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</h4>
      <p class="list-group-item-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eget interdum libero. Vivamus pharetra faucibus.</p>
      <span class="author-pubdate-info">Autor: John Doe | Fecha: 11 de Noviembre de 2014</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks! Your answer came first, voting as the right one.

Comment: Also, place the transition to the non hover state like in my updated answer :)

Comment: Yes I notice that it didn't have the transition when going back from hover so I added it. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Also, if you change `overflow-y: scroll` to `overflow-y: auto;` you will only get a scrollbar if the content overflows.

Answer (score 1):

Just trigger the `h4` on hover:

```
.list-group-item-switchhon-blog:hover h4{
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  color: #fff;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/y7d5fm1w/1/)

UPDATE

A better way is actually setting the `h4` to inherit the color from it's parent:

```
.list-group-item-switchhon-blog h4{
 color: inherit !important;
}
```

That way you don't have to duplicate code and add extra code for the hover out

[NEW FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/y7d5fm1w/2/)

Comment: Your answer came second, however I upvoted yours. Thanks! Works great!